# android take photo using android front camera not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to take photo with front camara in my android app, i am tried this code but not not working all time opening back camara. My code is.

```
Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();

callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);//camera application is called to capture

File photoFile = null;
try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, activityStartCameraApp);
```

Comment: have you try changine `callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)` to 'callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 0)` ,  most camera have an Int value, am guessing the `1` is referencing the front camera , changing it to `0` may switch to back camera

Comment: @MuyideIbukun not working

Comment: oh, then not sure what the problem is for now, code seem correct

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Google Camera's shortcut for Android 7.1 (but should work with older Androids)

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
```

So, combined with previous answers, this works for me on all phones I could've test it on

```
 intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more feature permission in this way:

```
<!--Front camera-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

IMO, using front camera with *Intent* isn't very well documented also not working in most devices.

You can use camera preview class defined as a  [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) that can display the live image data coming from a camera, so users can frame and capture a picture or video. The class implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` in order to capture the callback *events* for creating and destroying the view, which are needed for assigning the camera preview input.

```
private Camera openFrontCamera() {
      int cameraCount = 0;
      Camera cam = null;
      Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
      cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
      for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
         Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
         if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
               cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
              // Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
         }
      }

      return cam;
   }
```

---

```
  @Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      //Creates a Camera object to access a particular hardware camera.
      // and throw a RuntimeException if camera is opened by other applications
      mCamera =openFrontCamera();         
      try {       
         mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```